# Django adding to database with form

Tags: python, django, database, python-2.7, model-view-controller

I tried adding to my database (which is a list of colleges), with a form, but it is not working. Any idea why? It's bringing me to the success page, but not actually adding it to the database

Model:

```
class College(models.Model):
    college_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to="logos", default="logos/default.png")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.college_name
    @classmethod
    def create(cls, college_name):
        college = cls(college_name = college_name)
        return college
```

View:

```
def add(request):
    return render(request, 'app/add.html')

def add_college(request):
    school = request.POST.get('collegename_input', '')
    College.create(school)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('add_success')

def add_success(request):
    return render(request, 'app/add_success.html')
```

add.html:

```
<h2> Add your school </h2>
    <form action="{% url 'app:addcollege' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="collegename_input">School: </label>
        <input type="text" id="collegename_input" name="collegename_input" />
        <input type="submit" value="Add School" />
    </form>
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Your view to process the POST request looks like it is incorrect because it is not creating/saving the model properly.  In order to save the `College`, you should do the following:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def add_college(request):
    school = request.POST.get('collegename_input', '')
    # College.create(school)
    college = College(school_name=school)
    college.save()
    return redirect('add_success')
```